# How to get Ansible to return 'OK' (nothing changed) when initiating a PowerShell script?

Tags: powershell, ansible

Usually when Ansible kicks off a PowerShell script with `win_command`/`win_shell`/`win_psexec`, as long as it doesn't run into errors it'll return `changed`, because of course it doesn't know what all the script did.

Since we can return any exit code in a PowerShell script is there a way, via exit codes or otherwise, to notify Ansible that there was no change required so that Ansible returns an `OK` status?

Or will it always return `changed` no matter what (assuming no failure)?

Comment: See [defining changed](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_error_handling.html#defining-changed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *it'll return `changed`, because of course it doesn't know what all the script did*

Right, because of that that is the defined default behavior for this type of module(s).

Regarding your question

> *Since we can return any exit code in a PowerShell script is there a way, via exit codes or otherwise, to notify Ansible that there was no change required so that Ansible returns an `OK` status?*

this is already the correct idea. In other words, yes, such kind of behavior is possible.

Additionally to the already given comment about [Defining `changed`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_error_handling.html#defining-changed), one'll need also [Defining failure](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_error_handling.html#defining-failure). This is because a `non-zero return code` would result into an failure otherwise.

The minimal example playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - name: Exec sh command
    shell:
      cmd: "echo ''; exit 254;"
    register: result
    failed_when: result.rc != 0 and result.rc != 254
    changed_when: result.rc != 254

  - name: Show result
    debug:
      msg: "{{ result }}"
```

will result into the output of

```yaml
TASK [Exec sh command] *****************

TASK [Show result] *********************
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg:
    changed: false
    cmd: echo ''; exit 254;
    delta: '0:00:00.012397'
    end: '2022-12-24 18:00:00.012397'
    failed: false
    failed_when_result: false
    msg: non-zero return code
    rc: 254
    start: '2022-12-24 18:00:00.000000'
    stderr: ''
    stderr_lines: []
    stdout: ''
    stdout_lines: []
```

**Similar Q&A**

- [`shell` command and set task `changed`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74910884/6771046)
- [`win_powershell` module accesses the `$Ansible` PowerShell variable](https://serverfault.com/a/1118762/448950)