# Ansible: check, that file has changed after shell command

Tags: ansible

I have a shell command in ansible, that changes some file. But most of the time, file stays the same.

What is a preferred way to compare the content of the file before/after shell command and set task `changed` property?

Comment: You can try matching the md5 checksum of the file (before and after states).

Comment: Can you provide more details about the shell command, the kind of file and what gets changed? Otherwise an answer will be more a guess. In example, how about to check the timestamps of the files and when it was last touched?

Answer (score 1):

Q: ***"Compare the content of the file before/after the shell command and set task changed."***

A: Make the script report the changes, register the output of the shell command, and test *changed_when*.

For example, the task below sets a random environment variable *RANDOM_TEXT* and writes it to the file */tmp/test.ansible*. If the file changes the script will report *changed*. Because of the potentially failing *diff* you have to set *ignore_errors: true*

```yaml
    - shell: "sh -c 'cp /tmp/test.ansible /tmp/test.ansible.orig;
                     echo $RANDOM_TEXT > /tmp/test.ansible;
                     if (diff /tmp/test.ansible.orig /tmp/test.ansible > /dev/null);
                     then echo not changed;
                     else echo changed;
                     fi'"
      environment:
        RANDOM_TEXT: "{{ lookup('random_choice', 'AAA', 'BBB') }}"
      ignore_errors: true
      register: result
      changed_when: result.stdout == 'changed'
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  tasks:

    - shell: "sh -c 'cp /tmp/test.ansible /tmp/test.ansible.orig;
                     echo $RANDOM_TEXT > /tmp/test.ansible;
                     if (diff /tmp/test.ansible.orig /tmp/test.ansible > /dev/null);
                     then echo not changed;
                     else echo changed;
                     fi'"
      environment:
        RANDOM_TEXT: "{{ lookup('random_choice', 'AAA', 'BBB') }}"
      ignore_errors: true
      register: result
      changed_when: result.stdout == 'changed'

    - debug:
        var: result
```